# How to save the location of the bar that closes above or below the box

Tags: pine-script

I want to delete a box if a candle went above the candle that closed above or below the box, but I have a problem with not knowing how to store the location of the candle that closed above or below the box

This is my code and I want the purple box to be removed when passes the yellow line but its removing the box when any candle goes above or below the previous one.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkOs2.jpg)

```
 if reg_fvg.size() > 0

        for i = reg_fvg.size() - 1 to 0

            remove_bull = reg_fvg_side.get(i) == 'bull' and tf_c.get(0) < reg_fvg.get(i).get_bottom() and tf_l.get(0) > low

            remove_bear = reg_fvg_side.get(i) == 'bear' and tf_c.get(0) > reg_fvg.get(i).get_top() and tf_h.get(0) < high
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP9Kz.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQO6D.jpg)

Comment: Why do you need the location of the candle? You only need the price value, if I got it right.

Comment: @karatedog any solution dear, just keep in mind first comparison the candle must close and the second any candle must go above the high of the closed one